How often (and when) is main.dart called in Flutter when an app is running?
A simple question related to app initialisation in main.dart.
I am calling a .setData() method to load a UserModel in main before the App is returned. This UserModel then persists as a static class throughout. This works as I need it to. However, one of the variables is a String of the Current Month. As the Class is static, I am unsure if I will be able to detect if the month has changed using this function (if the app is left running overnight on the last day of a month, for example). So my quesiton is when is main() called? Is it everytime the app is openend? And therefore, my setData(); function is called each time? Or is it less frequent than this? I am using Riverpod for other providers throughout the class but I need to know the UserModel values outside of a Provider. Thanks

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await UserModel().setData();
 
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: InheritedConsumer(child: CGC())));
}


I believe main() is called only once.  If you have something that must change at local midnight, set up a service that returns a cached value as long as the day is "today".

Can confirm that main() only gets called once, when the app starts. So you can either restart the app periodically (say once a day or once a month), or you can make the provider change its data while the app is running.

Once the app is running, the main.dart file is not called again during typical app lifecycle events (like the app being paused, resumed, or backgrounded). Instead, Flutter manages the lifecycle using widgets like WidgetsBindingObserver or specific lifecycle methods (didChangeAppLifecycleState). It is called again during a hot restart or when the app is fully restarted by the system or user

The main() function is the entry point for applications and is called one time.
You can use the WidgetsBindingObserver to detect when your app returns from onResume and update the thing that you need.
In some cases when your app is open and in the background, the system could close your app and when you open again is the same as if you open the app for the first time.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html
